# Remap key that is assigned to multiple keys

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, powertoys, sharpkeys

I recently bought a keyboard that has one of its keys assigned to left windows + C and I'm trying to remap it.

sharpkeys is only recognising it as being mapped to left windows. Power toys is picking up that its mapped to multiple keys but wont remap it (it remapped me typing windows + C normally but typing the key itself doesn't seem to work).

Anany ideas on how I could remap it?

Answer (score 0):

Keycodes mappings by sharpkeys or Power toys are found in the registry
under the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`.

Use `regedit` and navigate to this key. If any mapping was done,
you would have there a value named "Scancode Map".

You may export the key for backup, then delete the Scancode item
and reboot. This will undo any mapping and return Windows to
the default keyboard layout.

If no Scancode item was found in the registry, then some other method
was used. The likely reason is then that the wrong keyboard layout
was used for Windows. You'll need in this case to find the right
keyboard layout, or use applications such sharpkeys or Power toys
or AutoHotKey to correct it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the keyboard sends the actual Left Windows + C key combination.

This could be remapped to something else with AutoHotkey:

```
#c::send, MyText
```

But then also manually pressing Left Windows + C would be remapped accordingly.